# wait for async call with runloop runmode in action-target function

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

I have this code running in a target-action click from NSOutlineView. The goal is to finish each request (originally a web service request) before starting a new request from new clicks on NSOutlineView. This works, but the UI becomes unresponsive on the third click until the current async call finishes. What I am missing?

```
- (void) showMarket:(NSString *)market sender:(id) sender {

    do {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    } while (loadingMarket);

    loadingMarket = true;

    NSLog(@"loading market %@", market);
    [sender beginProgress:self];


    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"loaded market %@", market);
        [sender endProgress:self];
        loadingMarket = false;
    });




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the currentRunLoop from the same currentRunLoop is totally not a good idea. I don't think it is reentrant. Use a serial dispatch queue for a serial task. Take a look at [the Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign.html).